# java.io.OptionalDataException in run method?

Tags: java, networking, client

Why I receive `java.io.OptionalDataException` in the run method?

ObjectInputStream reads items & users couple times, then it crashes with `OptionalDataException`. I think it relates `EOFException`.

It prints a message when new socket created
It print the value of objectInputStream
It also prints the message

#### STACK TRACE + MESSAGES

New socket created 
New socket created 
New socket created 
Here is ObjectInputStream :java.io.ObjectInputStream@1430b5c 
Here is message :REA:ITEM: 
Here is ObjectInputStream :java.io.ObjectInputStream@1decdec <
Here is message :ADD:ITEM: 
New socket created 
New socket created 
Here is ObjectInputStream :java.io.ObjectInputStream@b2fd8f 
Here is message :REA:ITEM: 
New socket created 
**java.io.OptionalDataException** 
                  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source) 
                  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source) 
                  
at fedaih.SocketTask.run(SocketTask.java:55) 
                  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
New socket created 
Here is ObjectInputStream :java.io.ObjectInputStream@1c39a2d 
Here is message :REA:USER: 
Here is ObjectInputStream :java.io.ObjectInputStream@13bad12 
Here is message :ADD:USER: 
New socket created 
New socket created 
Here is ObjectInputStream :java.io.ObjectInputStream@eb7859 
Here is message :REA:USER: 
**java.io.OptionalDataException** 
                  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source) 
                  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source) 
                  
at fedaih.SocketTask.run(SocketTask.java:55) 
                  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
public void run() {
        
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        User user = null;
        Item item = null;
        String upc = null;
        String username = null;
        
        // This is the line where the error occurs
        String message = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
        switch (message) {
        
            case "REA:ITEM:":   upc = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                                item = inventoryFileManager.readItem(upc);
                                objectOutputStream.writeObject(item);
                                objectOutputStream.flush();
                                break;
                                
            case "REA:USER:":   username = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                                user = userFileManager.readUser(username);
                                objectOutputStream.writeObject(user);
                                objectOutputStream.flush();
                                break;
            
            case "REM:ITEM:":   upc = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                                inventoryFileManager.removeItem(upc);
                                break;
                                
            case "REM:USER:":   username = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                                userFileManager.removeUser(username);
                                break;
            
            case "ADD:ITEM:":   item = (Item) objectInputStream.readObject();
                                if (item != null) {
                                        inventoryFileManager.addItem(item);
                                }
                                break;
                                
            case "ADD:USER:":   user = (User) objectInputStream.readObject();
                                if (user != null) {
                                        userFileManager.addUser(user);
                                }
                                break;
                        
            case "UPD:ITEM:":   item = (Item) objectInputStream.readObject();
                                inventoryFileManager.updateItem(item);
                                break;
                
            case "UPD:USER:":   user = (User) objectInputStream.readObject();
                                userFileManager.updateUser(user);
                                break;
                                
            case "ALL:ITEM:":   objectOutputStream.writeObject(inventoryFileManager.readAllItems());
                                objectOutputStream.flush();
                                break;
                
            case "ALL:USER:":   objectOutputStream.writeObject(userFileManager.readAllUsers());
                                objectOutputStream.flush();
        }
        objectOutputStream.close();
        objectInputStream.close();
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PointOfSaleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the full exception stack trace, so we can see some more detail about the reason for the exception.

Comment: How was the data *written* to the stream?

Comment: Have you read the exceptions information? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OptionalDataException.html

So if you can catch the exception and out print it's eof and length value would help track down the issue also.

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc explains the exception as follows:

> Exception indicating the failure of an object read operation due to unread primitive data, or the end of data belonging to a serialized object in the stream. This exception may be thrown in two cases:
>
> - An attempt was made to read an object when the next element in the stream is primitive data. In this case, the OptionalDataException's length field is set to the number of bytes of primitive data immediately readable from the stream, and the eof field is set to false.
> - An attempt was made to read past the end of data consumable by a class-defined readObject or readExternal method. In this case, the OptionalDataException's eof field is set to true, and the length field is set to 0.

In short, there is a mismatch between what was written to the socket and what your code is attempting to read.  To get to the bottom of this, you need to:

- find out what the values of `eof` and `length` in the exception are, and
- tie down the circumstances under which the failure is occuring.

Then, compare your code against the code that writes the objects and (using the evidence above) figure out what the mismatch is.

Comment: Problem caused by using writeUTF(), instead of writeObject() in one of the methods in the Model.

Comment: I was using write(bytes) and reading as readObject. so changed to writeObject and readObject and exception is solved :-) thnx